# python open() - access denied

Tags: python, file-io, stdin

This is my first post on stackoverflow, so if somethings wrong I'm eager to learn!

I'm programming a plugin for Cinema 4d with python. Everything works on Mac, but I'm having problems on Windows with what I'm about to explain.

The plugin needs a path to a server, in case of rendering on a renderserver. I want the user to enter the path once, and to then store it in a .txt file.

for c4d, plugins are being installed, by draging-and-droping the plugin into the plugin folder at for example:

C:/programm files/Maxon/Cinema4D/Plugins/NewPluginGoesHere

In Order to keep everything nice and clean, I want the pathToServer.txt (text file that only stores one line with the path) in the plugin folder as well. When Installing (droping) the plugin into said folder, the .txt file is already there -> Not created by the plugin.

Here comes the problem:

I open and write to the file with

```
pathFile = open(pathToPathFile, "w")
pathFile.write(pathToServerFolder)
```

Works fine on mac, but throws

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\MAXON\\CINEMA 4D R14\\plugins\\MultiLayerRender\\Renderserverpath.txt'
```

on Windows.

I'm pretty inexperienced with using python for such tasks (like file management).

I then tried the following:

```
pathFile = subprocess.Popen(pathToPathFile, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
pathFile.communicate(input = pathToServerFolder)
pathFile.stdin.close()
```

Which doesn't give me an error, but it also doesn't seem to do anything :/

I read throung the python documentation of subprocess, but that realy didn't help me at all, if anything, it confused me.

I noticed, that I also need to run my code editor in Admin Mode, in order for it to have permission to save directly into the plugin folder in said directory. It seems like files in the 'program files' folder are somehow protected. Also, this plugin will be installed on several different computers either mac or windows, and therefor changing permission on for example the programm files folder is not an option. In the end draging and droping should be all one has to do in order to install it.

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Comment: This is actually quite a nice first post. You showed us your code, you gave us your exact error message, and you also explained your thoughts on what the problem might be and why particular solutions wouldn't work. Nice job!

Comment: Not sure why you thought subprocesses would help, though...

Answer (score 2):

You need elevated permissions to write to Program Files on Windows, somehow your plugin does not have them. I would consider just using another directory.

Many render solutions requires you to specify a directory somewhere, so I don't think it's a huge problem. modo 501 and 601 (and 701 presumably), for example needs a directory somewhere for data sharing. V-Ray for Maya more or less requires you to put the scene files on a shared drive in distributed mode.

Comment: That answer came fast! Thank you - May i ask which folder is commonly being used for such a thing? or where to create one? Thanks

Comment: I don't know how the big studios do it, they probably solve it on their own. But a network drive is common. modo needs you to go into Preferences and specify a shared folder somewhere where it will put the scene files. Sadly I have no experience with Cinema 4D so I don't know how it does it. V-Ray for Maya needs to be able to access your textures and stuff, and that basically means a folder every render node can access, ergo a network folder.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure exactly what you want to store. In your case it seems like just Plugin settings, my answer is more about the scene files in general. But maybe that is part of the problem as well?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, it is just about that one setting/path. There is a folder in Application data, from c4d, and i think I'm gonna store it there ;) Thanks for your fast answers!